# Java - Superclass Fields Not Properly Being Changed

Tags: java, libgdx, subclass, superclass

I have two classes, Entity and Ship where Ship extends Entity. In my entity class I have a private field speed. In my ship class I have a update method that is simply trying to increment speed by saying current speed + acceleration times a delta time.

Here is Entity:

```
private float   height, rotation, speed, width;

private Sprite  sprite;
private Vector2 origin, position;

public Entity (float x, float y) { position = new Vector2 (x, y); }

public Entity (float x, float y, Texture texture)
{
    this (x, y);

    if (texture != null)
    {
        sprite = new Sprite (texture);
        width = sprite.getWidth ();
        height = sprite.getHeight ();

        origin = new Vector2 (x + width / 2f, y + height / 2f);
    }

    else
    {
        sprite = null;
        origin = position;
    }
}

public Entity (float x, float y, float rotation, Texture texture)
{
    this (x, y, texture);

    this.rotation = rotation;
}

public Entity (float x, float y, float rotation, float speed, Texture texture)
{
    this (x, y, rotation, texture);

    this.speed = speed;
}

public float getHeight () { return height; }
public float getRotation () { return rotation; }
public float getSpeed () { return speed; }
public float getWidth () { return width; }
public float getX () { return position.x; }
public float getY () { return position.y; }

public void setPosition (Vector2 vector) { position = vector; }

public void setRotation (float value) { rotation = value; }
public void setSpeed (float value) { speed = value; }
public void setSprite (Sprite sprite) { this.sprite = sprite; }
public void setX (float value) { position.x = value; }
public void setY (float value) { position.y = value; }

public Sprite getSprite () { return sprite; }
public Vector2 getOrigin () { return origin; }
public Vector2 getPosition () { return position; }
```

And here is the `update()` method of Ship:

```
setSpeed (getSpeed () + acceleration * delta);
System.out.println (getSpeed ());
```

What I expect to happen is that speed is increased by whatever acceleration * delta is. However, what happens is that speed is set equal to that value, not incremented. If I set the fields in Entity to static then my code works, but I feel that I shouldn't do that. I've also tried setting the fields to protected and the Entity class to abstract but I still get the same effect. I'm really at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong, unless setting the fields to static is correct?

EDIT:
The entire update method of Ship.

```
public void update (float delta)
{
    // Updating the origin's position
    getOrigin ().set (getX () + getWidth () / 2f, getY () + getHeight () / 2f);

    updateTurrets (delta);
    updateBullets (delta);

    setSprite (updateSprite (delta));

    //calculateRotateTo (moveTo);
    setRotation (0f);
    rotateTo = getRotation ();

    if (getRotation () != rotateTo)
    {
        setRotation (rotateTo);
    }

    else if (getOrigin () != moveTo)
    {
        /*float currDistance = Utils.calculateDistance (originalPos, getOrigin ());
        float totDistance = Utils.calculateDistance (originalPos, moveTo);

        if (currDistance >= totDistance / 2f)
            accelerating = false;

        else
            accelerating = true;

        if (accelerating)
            setSpeed (getSpeed () + acceleration * delta);

        else
        {
            if (getSpeed () > 0f)
                setSpeed (getSpeed () - acceleration * delta);

            else
            {
                setSpeed (0f);
                setPosition (moveTo);
            }
        }*/

        setSpeed (getSpeed () + acceleration * delta);
        System.out.println (getSpeed ());
    }
}
```

EDIT #2: I did some extra testing and if I put a ship instance in the main render() method that LibGDX gives it works. Anywhere else however, it doesn't.

Comment: Is either acceleration or delta, zero? Recall Java's precedence rules.

Comment: No, delta is almost zero but not exactly zero.

Comment: What types are they? floats? Both of them?

Comment: Hmmm, can't figure this one. And can't see why static is better.

Comment: Exactly, but if I set speed to static then it works but I feel like I shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: Do you override `setSpeed()` in `Ship`? If yes, please post the code.

Comment: setSpeed() is never overridden. Everything else in the Ship class only manipulates fields in Ship.

Comment: I guess you have an `update()` method, right?

Comment: Yes, which has delta as a parameter.

Comment: OK, please post the full method.

Comment: Are you sure  acceleration is greater than zero?

Comment: Yes, the acceleration of the ship I'm testing is 5f.

Comment: When you make the call to getSpeed() in your update() method, what is the value it returns (before you increment it)?

Comment: Before using setSpeed() it returns 0 as speed is 0 at creation of a ship. After calling setSpeed(getSpeed() + acceleration * delta)) it varies from 0.7 to 0.8. With each update it should increase by that value but it instead stays at that value.

Comment: I think it's because of `getOrigin () != moveTo`. Try to replace it with `getOrigin.equals(moveTo);` Also you could try to run your code step by step in debugger. And no, do not use any static fields for this task.

Comment: That didn't change a thing, the code was executing like it should but at the end of the update method it was like speed was reverting back to it's original value of 0. I believe I fixed it though, by setting the entire object to static and leaving its fields to private or protected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I fixed it or at least as far as I can tell. Apparently saying `static Ship ship = new Ship ();` allowed for the fields to properly change without those fields also needing to be static.